# Just Beginning, need some help! InfiniTeX Problems?

Tags: editors, coding

I am just getting started in learning LaTeX! However, when I am writing some "code" to compile I am running into an error message. It could be the editor that I am using, for reference it is an editor called InfiniTeX. The message in question says this: Source

! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble. line: 14 \begin{document}\documentclass [a4,12pt]{book}"

[Here is the author's Github page.](https://github.com/fetacore/Infinitex). What is weird is that on Atom the same code compiles fine and I am able to produce a PDF no problem.

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{book}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\title{\Large{\textbf{LaTeX Tutorial}}}
\author{By Name Here}
\date{June 22,2020}
```

Any help for a newbie would be great! The editor that I am currently using is amazing and seems to have a lot of potentials to be what I am looking for in terms of my meeting my needs.  I would have used VSCode, but I have been running into errors over there as well.

Comment: \begin{document} should bei placed after \documentclass {......}

Comment: you seem to input your code into another document instead of running it as standalone code.

Comment: Hey Jens! Thanks for the tip! Also, Ulrike, could you clarify what you mean? What do you mean by "input my code into another document instead of running it as a standalone code? "

Comment: So this is the code on Atom, can anyone understand why it works there but not the other editor? Also, some advice on how to set this up on VScode is preferable to Atom.    [\documentclass{article}
\title{Title}
\author{Matthew Pine}
\begin{document}
\maketitle{}
\section{Introduction}
This is where you will write your content.
\end{document}]